# Observable collection removing item only once, when tried again doesnt work - Windows phone 8 - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I am writing my first application for WP8 platform in C#. I implemented three datatypes namely locationModel which has locationGroups. Each locationGroup has a ObservableCollection of type locationData.

locationData has two double types for latitude and longitude and a title string.

I used a textblock inside a stackpanel to show the locationData element's title, where the lat long are hidden to user. 
There is a context menu on each of this textblock element which enable the user to delete the respective locationData.
When I open the app and delete any item, it succesfully does and updates the view too. But when I do it for another item it just doesnt work. I cannot delete more than one items for each time I open the app.

I used breakpoints to see where the problem is. the selected locationData is succesfully passed to the App.ViewModel.LocationModel.Items.Remove(). But it just that they are not deleted from the observable collection. I even tried to see the index of the locationData in observable collection and use RemoveAt method. Even it doesnt work. 
I did a lot of research to find the problem, but no one seems to face the same problem as me. I referred to msdn article on how to implement inotifypropertychanged to update the collection. But its too complex for me to understand that.

I dont really understand why the observable collection delete the item for the second time even though if I pass the index of that item. And my usage of breakpoints showed me that the data is not even null.

So kindly tell me what is causing this problem and how do I overcome it so that I can implement my own workaround and not face this issue again. I can show you the code if you want me to.
Thanks.

CODE:
Adding an item

```
private void SaveLocationData(LocationData locationData)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        try
        {
            App.ViewModel.Custom.Items.Add(locationData);
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Custom);

            appSettings[LocationModel.CustomKey] = data;
            appSettings.Save();

            //Notify that data is changed
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        catch(IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Deleting item:

```
private void DeleteLocationData(LocationData locationData)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        try
        {
            App.ViewModel.Custom.Items.Remove(locationData);
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.Custom);

            appSettings[LocationModel.CustomKey] = data;
            appSettings.Save();

            //Notify that data is changed
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

        catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

One more thing that I want to say is, whenever I add a locationData to the collection, it updates automatically. Because adding is done on another page and when the mainpage.xaml loads(in which the observable collection data is), it updates automatically because of the code in OnNavigatedTo method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }

    }
```

And LoadData method is :

```
public void LoadData()
    {

        Custom = LoadCustomLocations();
        IsDataLoaded = true;

    }

    private LocationGroup LoadCustomLocations()
    {
        string dataFromAppSettings;
        LocationGroup data;

        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(CustomKey, out dataFromAppSettings))
        {
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationGroup>(dataFromAppSettings);
        }
        else
        { 
            data = new LocationGroup();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

So, can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add some code blocks to your question, that helps a bit to understand your question more easily, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you always do "RemoveAt(0)"? 
Does Custom.Items removes the element before you save it? What happens if you don't save and load your data in deletion? Thanks

Comment: @Matt When I hard code it to always remove 1st item using RemoveAt(0), it removes succesfully even multiple times. But the page updates with new list only for the first time. After that even if we remove everything, it doesnt update until I reload the app by closing and opening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you described on your comment I think you set the DataContext to your Items. When you create a new Items-List the DataContext will be lost. So you have to reset the DataContext to the new loaded Items-List

Comment: I don't think I need to reset the Datacontext because when I was deleting the second item I used break points to see if the DataContext is returning the correct longtapped item only to the code behind. And it does. 

Tell me if you want to see any more of my code if it helps you in any way. I think the real culprit is Observalble Collection only.

Comment: In this case, please remove the line " App.ViewModel.LoadData();" in your DeleteLocationData and tell me, if this works or not. Thanks

Comment: It is probably the DataContext. When you load the Data first time, you create the object custom_1. You bind the Items-List items_1 to your ListBox.
When you press delete, you remove the item at items_1. But then you create a new object custom_2 with items_2. While the ListBox will still show the items_1 collection you remove the items in items_2, items_3 and so on. That's why you need to set the DataContext to the new Custom.Items (or LayoutRoot-DataContext to new created Custom object). Otherwise, you don't need to load the Data you just saved ;)

Comment: Oh I see. That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot Matt.